# How to scroll a div to the bottom after appending something to that div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I am currently using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270612/scroll-to-bottom-of-div) to scroll a div to the bottom by writing something like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#comment_list').scrollTop($('#comment_list').scrollHeight)
}
```

But I noticed that when I try to `.append()` something to `#comment_list` then do the above code. It doesn't actually scroll to the bottom (maybe the `.scrollHeight` is a static value?).

For example, this won't work

```
$('#comment_list').append('<div>something</div>').scrollTop($('#comment_list').scrollHeight)
```

Neither will this

```
$('#comment_list').append('<div>something</div>')
$('#comment_list').scrollTop($('#comment_list').scrollHeight)
```

Do I need to use some other "trick" or something?

Any tips and suggestions welcomed. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried $("#comment_list").scrollTo('100%');?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
$('#comment_list').append( '<div>something</div>' );
$('#comment_list').scrollTo( '100%' );
```

Check [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/Bk5vV/) sample.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7114446/how-to-always-see-bottom-line-when-append-text-to-a-div)

Comment: How do I download `scrollTo`? The jQuery plugin site is kind of confusing. I got as far as [here](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/node/8283), but I don't see any download links. I also looked at the [demo](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/), but I don't see any download links there either...

Comment: I believe this to be a DOM function.. The jsFiddle sample doesn't make use of any plugins.

Comment: It wasn't part of the DOM. I actually found the latest version 1.4.2 [here](http://flesler-plugins.googlecode.com/files/jquery.scrollTo-1.4.2-min.js).

Answer (score 0):

The `scrollTop` function is called on `$(document).ready()` event.

This event is not fired when you append content to the `DIV` on the client-side.

So, after you append the content, you need to call the `scrollTop` once again to set it correctly:

```
$('#comment_list').append('<div>something</div>');
$('#comment_list').scrollTop('100%');
```

HTH