# Scrolling bottom div with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Use jQuery to scroll to the bottom of a div with lots of text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742346/use-jquery-to-scroll-to-the-bottom-of-a-div-with-lots-of-text)

I have a div where load a number of comments from a database. The div has a height expressed in em not px. It also has enabled the overflow.

When I write a comment and send it recharges I want the scroll to move to the end of the div.
Using `$("# boxcoment"). ScrollTop (400)` within the succes and working properly I automatically moves the scroll.

But I work with em and want to know if `.scrollTop()` works with em or if there is another way to scroll down to the end of the div.

I tried also with:

```
height = $("#boxcoment").height();
$("#boxcoment").scrollTop(height);
```

But the scroll just stops halfway.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `scrollHeight` property of the DOM Element object.

> Height of the scroll view of an element; it includes the element padding but not its margin.

```
var $box = $('#boxcoment'); 
var height = $box.get(0).scrollHeight;
$box.scrollTop(height);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  var docHeight = $(document).height();

  $("#boxcoment").scrollTop(docHeight);
  //or
  $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop:docHeight+'px'},444);
```