# Table body autoscroll with click event

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a requirement to create some input boxes while clicking add more button everytime. I am using jquery, but every time the scroll bar is not moving with the increment of the number of input boxes. It remains in the top, so after a maximum height is reached, new field are kept hidden. I have already used scrollTop but unable to fix it. Can anybody guide me.

`jQ2("#btnAddItem").click( function () {jQ2("#list_quick  > tbody").append('<tr><td...</td></tr>')}`

Thanks

Comment: create a jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net so it easier to help you

Answer (score 0):

Check here:
[Use jQuery to scroll to the bottom of a div with lots of text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742346/use-jquery-to-scroll-to-the-bottom-of-a-div-with-lots-of-text)

if it's ok, just attach it to `.click()` or other event of your choice.