# Ajax Call on End of Scroll Down of div

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a div with scroll.what i want to do is call a function when the scroll down of that div end or reached over there.how can i do that?Please help me.your suggestion might be helpful.
thanks in advance

Comment: Following this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742346/use-jquery-to-scroll-to-the-bottom-of-a-div-with-lots-of-text) might help you.

Comment: ok i will go through it