# JavaScript scroll and focus

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

In my application I have displayed records in div that is set to overflow : auto.
 The task I'am trying to accomplish is: After by clicking button adding new record to database, reload page and if content of my div is in overflow mode i would like to scrool down to  bottom of that div.
Also in my code behind after adding record i can obtain id of control that represents new record.

I'am using framework 1.1
 What steps/tehniques should I use to accomplish that task ?

Comment: you might want to try `overflow: scroll;`

Comment: I think you wanna when you scroll the mouse then display the data does i make sense or not?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742346/use-jquery-to-scroll-to-the-bottom-of-a-div-with-lots-of-text

Answer (score 3):

You can scroll to the last item with the function scrollIntoView. For exemple, if your div's id is "content" and your elements are 'p' :

```
var elements = document.getElementById('content').getElementsByTagName('p');
elements[elements.length - 1].scrollIntoView();
```