# How to set div scrollbar to bottom by default

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is div.

```
<div id='showmymessage' style="height:490px;overflow:auto;">
```

Hey nothing is working in my case. Div is set to `overflow:auto`.

I tried all these ways but scrollbar is not loading at bottom position.

1. `document.getElementById('showmymessage').scrollTop = 99999999999;`
2. `var myDiv = document.getElementById('showmymessage');
   myDiv.scrollTop = myDiv.scrollHeight;`
3. `$('#showmymessage').scrollTop($('#showmymessage')[0].scrollHeight);`

Please somebody tell if I made any mistake and try to help.

Comment: You tagged only PHP in your tags (it's adjusted), but you re posting JavaScript. There is a difference between that. As well, you 3rd option is a Jquery, did you include Jquery? Also please show us your code. With this whatyouposted now, we have no clue how we could solve your problem

Comment: @Dorvalla: yes I included jquery.. And i tried all these methods by calling a function and putting this code in it.

Answer (score 1):

You want `overflow:scroll` instead of overflow:auto.  Then your javascript should work.

**Update**

...then again, there's another question very similar where it works with overflow:auto.

[Use jQuery to scroll to the bottom of a div with lots of text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742346/use-jquery-to-scroll-to-the-bottom-of-a-div-with-lots-of-text)

It looks like it uses the same as your version 3.  Working example:

http://jsbin.com/ucinu

Possibly something else wrong with your code?  Check for missing closing tags, javascript errors etc?