# Make overflowing content scroll above element (instead of below)

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a chat page on my website.  One of the important features of this application is that old messages should be pushed up on the chat output area whenever a new message is received.

The user should be able to scroll up to see messages in the chronological order that they were received.  I have tried to do this (http://jsfiddle.net/wasingej/rqee378d/).  However, I cannot scroll up to see the overflowing content.

This works fine when content is overflowing below my element (http://jsfiddle.net/wasingej/rqee378d/3/).

All that has changed between the two is the `bottom` property has been changed to `top`.  Why won't my scroll bar appear in the first example?

Comment: Can you use JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this much simpler?

http://jsfiddle.net/rqee378d/4/

```
div.outer
{
    position: relative;
    min-height: 20px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

div
{
    position: relative;
}
```

And adding the text using a prepend.

http://api.jquery.com/prepend/

Comment: If you want the last piece of text to show in the viewport. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742346/use-jquery-to-scroll-to-the-bottom-of-a-div-with-lots-of-text

Comment: The problem with this is that all text will appear at the top of the container div.  I want text to appear at the bottom of the container div and expand up as I add more text.  The scroll bar should appear when text expands above the top of the container div.

Answer (score 0):

Your scroll bar wont appear in your first example because you are positioning the element using `absolute`. Please [read more about positioning here](https://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/). Here is a quote:

> What is happening is the absolutely positioned elements are
>   positioning themselves in relation to the **body** element instead of
>   their direct parent.

This is why your scrollbar is not appearing. If you make them `block` elements with a position of `static` then scrolling would work fine.