# jQuery/JavaS function to show div and smooth scroll down to it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div whose id is 'regOrg' and initially it is hidden using a css

```
display: none;
```

The link to be clicked has an id of `back`.
On clicking a link I want it to show and smooth scroll down to it (the div `regOrg`).

This is the code i have:

```
function goBack() {
    $("#regOrg").show();
    $("#back").click(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollBottom: $("#regOrg").offset().bottom
        }, 2000);
    });
}
```

I call the function `goback()` on the `onclick` event of the hyperlink. 
However it doesn't work. **It only shows the div but doesn't scroll to it.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I scroll to a specific location on the page using jquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586341/how-can-i-scroll-to-a-specific-location-on-the-page-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

You are not executing the scroll. You are just binding it to the click event.

Try:

```
function goBack() {
  $("#regOrg").show();
  $('html, body').animate({
     scrollBottom: $("#regOrg").offset().bottom + 'px'},2000);
}
```

EDIT: I added the missing "px" to it.

Comment: I tried that and it doesn't work. It still just opens the div but does anyone scroll to it

Answer (score 0):

Try with something like this :

```
function goBack() {
  $("#regOrg").show();
  var myDiv = $('#regOrg');
  var height = myDiv[0].scrollHeight;
  myDiv.scrollTop(height);
}
```

It works on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/en48qufu/1/)
You could take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742346/use-jquery-to-scroll-to-the-bottom-of-a-div-with-lots-of-text/) too.

Comment: What if the div is at the bottom?

Comment: Could you post your HTML ?