# Auto horizontal scroll when content is added

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, node.js, horizontal-scrolling

I am making a live twitter feed using nodejs and websockets. I am trying to get the display to automatically scroll to the left once the browser window is full and stop it overflowing vertically.

The project will be displayed on a fixed screen with so theres no need to worry about the browser resizing. Here's what I have so far:

```js
socket.onmessage = function(message) {
  var d = JSON.parse(message.data);
  console.log(message.data);
  var obj = {
    text: d.text,
    imgURL: d.imgURL,
  }
  updateView(obj);
}

var updateView = function(obj) {
  container.append("<span class='inner'><img class='profile' src=" + obj.imgURL +
    "></img><p>" + obj.text + "</p></span>");
}
```

```css
span#container {
  width: 1450px;
  min-width: 100px;
  min-height: 100%;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

span.inner {
  float: left;
  border: 1px #333333 solid;
  width: 469px;
  height: 450px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742346/use-jquery-to-scroll-to-the-bottom-of-a-div-with-lots-of-text ?

Comment: @RichardHousham: I don't think so... OP talks about horizontal scroll.

Comment: @user1756180 check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45822166/auto-horizontal-scroll-when-content-is-added/45822849#45822849

Answer (score 0):

Try this if `container` is a JavaScript DOM element:

```
$(container).scrollLeft(0);
```

Or this if `container` is a jQuery element:

```
container.scrollLeft(0);
```

[`.scrollLeft()` documentation](https://api.jquery.com/scrollleft/).

Answer (score 0):

For `div#container` element first get it's `scrollWidth` and then use `scrollLeft` on that element.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let elem = $('#container');
  let x = elem.get(0).scrollWidth;
  elem.scrollLeft(x);
});
```

```css
#container {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
SomeContent Here.SomeContent Here.SomeContent Here.SomeContent Here.SomeContent Here.SomeContent Here.SomeContent Here.SomeContent Here.SomeContent Here.SomeContent Here.SomeContent Here.Here.SomeContent Here.SomeContent Here.SomeContent Here.Here.SomeContent Here.SomeContent Here.SomeContent Here.Here.SomeContent Here.SomeContent Here.SomeContent Here.Here.SomeContent Here.SomeContent Here.SomeContent Here.Here.SomeContent Here.SomeContent Here.SomeContent Here.Here.SomeContent Here.SomeContent Here.SomeContentSomeContent Here.SomeContent Here.SomeContent Here.Here.SomeContent Here.SomeContent Here.Here.SomeContent Here.SomeContent Here.Here.SomeContent Here.SomeContent Here.SomeContentHere.SomeContent Here.SomeContent Here.Here.SomeContent Here.SomeContent Here.SomeContentHere.SomeContent Here.SomeContent Here.Here.SomeContent Here.SomeContent Here.SomeContentHere.SomeContent Here.SomeContent Here.Here.SomeContent Here.SomeContent Here.SomeContentHere.SomeContent Here.SomeContent Here.Here.SomeContent Here.SomeContent Here.SomeContentHere.SomeContent Here.SomeContent Here.Here.SomeContent Here.SomeContent Here.SomeContentHere.SomeContent Here.SomeContent Here.Here.SomeContent Here.SomeContent Here.SomeContent Here.SomeContent Here.SomeContent Here.Here.SomeContent Here.SomeContent Here.SomeContent Here.SomeContent Here.SomeContent Here.Here.SomeContent Here.SomeContent Here.SomeContentHere.SomeContent Here.SomeContent Here.Here.SomeContent Here.SomeContent Here.Here.SomeContent Here.SomeContent Here.Here.SomeContent Here.SomeContent Here.SomeContentHere.SomeContent Here.SomeContent Here.Here.SomeContent Here.SomeContent Here.SomeContent Here.SomeContent Here.SomeContent Here.Here.SomeContent Here.SomeContent Here.Here.Here.SomeContent Here.SomeContent Here.SomeContent Here.Here.SomeContent Here.SomeContent Here.SomeContent Here.SomeContent Here.SomeContent Here.SomeContent Here.SomeContent Here.SomeContent Here.SomeContent Here.SomeContent Here.SomeContent Here.SomeContent Here.SomeContent Here.SomeContent Here.SomeContent Here.SomeContent Here.SomeContent Here. SomeContent Here.SomeContent Here.SomeContent Here.SomeContent Here.SomeContent Here.SomeContent Here.SomeContent Here.SomeContent Here.SomeContent Here.SomeContent Here.
</div>
```

Hope, this works for you. :)

Comment: Thanks but this is still rendering in a grid, wrapping vertically. I probably didnt explain very well but I would like each tweet to appear to the right of the previous one and then scroll the whole container left once the screen width is full. If that makes sense :/